# Can I set the request header to render javascript without doing the submit with Ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have the following link on a page:

```
<a href="/items/14" class="srh" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" src="/images/delete.png?1335803006" /></a>
```

Note the class 'srh' which would trigger the following jQuery script when clicked.

```
$('.srh').click(function() {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
});
```

My intent was to set the request header to render text/javascript on the next page but I am getting a 406 error. Is my jQuery syntax wrong? Is there not enough time to set the header before the page is called? Should I have the jQuery script execute the page request after the header is set?

Answer (score 1):

If the server is responding to you with a 406, it means that it cannot generate a response body with the media type you requested.

You asked the server to generate a response with the `text/javascript` media type.  Your server said "I can't do that" and responded with a 406.

Check the response headers to see which types your server was willing to accept.  A good server will tell you that.

Comment: It is looking for text/html. I am trying to reset the header with jQuery to be looking for a javascript file.

Comment: When you set the accept header, you are asking the server to send you back something of that media type _if it can_.  If the server cannot, it will respond with a 406.  Can you change the server to send back a response of type `text/javascript`?

Comment: The jQuery script under application.js above is the portion of the Ajax syntax that resets the header to respond with media type `text/javascript`